# How to change and insert into new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

This is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 50 
    ch.CharName16, it.OptLevel, obj.ReqLevel1, item.ItemClass  
FROM 
    _Items as it            
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_Inventory] as inv ON it.ID64 = inv.ItemID   
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_Char] as ch ON inv.CharID = ch.CharID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_RefObjCommon] as obj ON it.RefItemID = obj.ID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_RefObjItem] as item ON obj.Link = item.ID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_BindingOptionWithItem] as adv ON it.ID64 = adv.nItemDBID            
WHERE 
    ch.CharName16 IS NOT NULL 
    AND CodeName128 NOT LIKE '%stone%' 
    AND CharName16 NOT LIKE '%]%'           
ORDER BY 
    it.OptLevel DESC, obj.ReqLevel1 DESC, item.ItemClass DESC,
    adv.nOptValue DESC
```

The results of the query:

[image: query results]

I want to add these to new table but like this:

[image: desired results]

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you inserting this into an existing table?  What does that table look like?  If it's really a new table, what do you want the new table to look like?  Just those fields?  Also, do you mean you want the fields added together like `1 + 2 = 3`, or just combined like `'1' + '2' = '12'`?

Comment: @BaconBits  I created new table like that. I can insert but like query' table. I want to add like new table's image. OptLevel = Sum of OptLevel in query image. ReqLevel =  Sum of ReqLevel in query image. Total Point = Sum of OptLevel and ReqLevel.

Comment: @Dtractus You want to insert the result which is in image 1 but also add one more column to that result which is `Total Point` into another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your query with an Outer Query that performs the necessary aggregations you need to roll the data up as pictured in your desired results (you'll need to remove the ORDER BY if you remove the TOP 50). Then perform your INSERT with the aggregated data. Something like this should work just fine.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(
        CharName16
        , OptLevel
        , ReqLevel1
        , ItemClass
        , TotalPoint
        )
SELECT CharName16
        , SUM(OptLevel) AS OptLevel
        , SUM(ReqLevel1) AS ReqLevel1
        , SUM(ItemClass) AS ItemClass
        , SUM(OptLevel) + SUM(ReqLevel1) + SUM(ItemClass) AS TotalPoint
  FROM (
        SELECT TOP 50 ch.CharName16, it.OptLevel, obj.ReqLevel1, item.ItemClass  
          FROM _Items as it            
          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[_Inventory] as inv ON it.ID64 = inv.ItemID   
          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[_Char] as ch ON inv.CharID = ch.CharID           
          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[_RefObjCommon] as obj ON it.RefItemID = obj.ID           
          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[_RefObjItem] as item ON obj.Link = item.ID           
          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[_BindingOptionWithItem] as adv ON it.ID64 = adv.nItemDBID            
         WHERE ch.CharName16 IS NOT NULL 
           AND CodeName128 NOT LIKE '%stone%' 
           AND CharName16 NOT LIKE '%]%'           
       ) tbl
 GROUP BY CharName16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 50  
    ch.CharName16, 
    Sum(it.OptLevel)as OptLevel, 
    Sum(obj.ReqLevel1)as ReqLevel1, 
    Sum(item.ItemClass) as ItemClass,
    Sum(SUM(it.OptLevel)+ SUM(obj.ReqLevel1)+ SUM(item.ItemClass)) as TotalPoint

 INTO NEWTABLE

FROM 
    _Items as it            
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_Inventory] as inv ON it.ID64 = inv.ItemID   
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_Char] as ch ON inv.CharID = ch.CharID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_RefObjCommon] as obj ON it.RefItemID = obj.ID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_RefObjItem] as item ON obj.Link = item.ID           
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[_BindingOptionWithItem] as adv ON it.ID64 = adv.nItemDBID            
WHERE 
    ch.CharName16 IS NOT NULL 
    AND CodeName128 NOT LIKE '%stone%' 
    AND CharName16 NOT LIKE '%]%'           
ORDER BY 
    it.OptLevel DESC, obj.ReqLevel1 DESC, item.ItemClass DESC,
    adv.nOptValue DESC
```